# Why is "the Jacobian" used to refer to matrix and its determinant?

Tags: terminology

[Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Jacobian.html) states (where $J$ is the Jacobian Matrix):

> The determinant of J is the Jacobian determinant (confusingly, often called "the Jacobian" as well) ...

Why would people refer to the Jacobian determinant and the Jacobian Matrix by the same name?

Comment: Because they do, even though it is confusing?

Comment: The difference hardly ever matters because context informs you.  Not a big deal.

Comment: because it's practically the same thing; the matrix is roughly meaningless since it's the determinant that we care about

Comment: @user29418 why?

Comment: ["One of the miseries of life is that everybody names things a little bit wrong, and so it makes everything a little harder to understand."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKWGGDXe5MA&feature=youtu.be&t=296) -- Richard Feynman

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChangeofVariablesTheorem.html

Comment: @user29418 That's far from the truth. Eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix are a big part of stability analysis in differential equations. For a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the Jacobian is $J = (\nabla f)^T$, and the Jacobian of *that* is the Hessian matrix, present in multivariate Taylor series, among other things.

Comment: To complicate things further, when people say they need the Jacobian determinant, they typically actually want the absolute value of the Jacobian determinant.

Comment: Usually there's some kind of bifurcation between two groups who use the matrix/determinant (maybe, say, in different mathematical fields where it was used independently). Both acknowledge Jacobi for its invention, but neither communicated with the other enough to standardise a notation. Also, possibly, the interest in the determinant pre-dated interest in the matrix, and so a few enterprising mathematicians decided to try to reassign the "Jacobean" handle to something more general.

Comment: For the same reason that “linear” refers to at least two different things?

Comment: And if you want to make a real mess of the nomenclature, start considering Jacobian determinants of complex transformations, which aren't the absolute value of determinant of the Jacobian at all, at least when cast in full complex form.

Answer (score 1):

From a historical perspective, matrices came relatively late. The Wikipedia article [Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) states:

> The term "matrix" (Latin for "womb", derived from mater—mother[106]) was coined by James Joseph Sylvester in 1850

Jacobi died in 1851. Thus, when he invented the Jacobian determinant he did not use the term "matrix". Determinants were known for a long time before that name was used for them. It makes sense to call the particular determinant of Jacobi a "Jacobian" when it is understood that the determinant is being used. Otherwise, the name to use is "Jacobian Matrix".

Answer (score 0):

The determinant is often learned about, and used in contexts of calc 3 math when people start learning about multiple integrals and use the Jacobian determinant when performing change of variables.

The actual Jacobian matrix (and to a degree its determinant), has applications outside just performing change of variables. People typically call either "The Jacobian" typically because whether its the Jocobian determinate or Matrix can be deduced from the context on which it is used, so it becomes an "informal" way of addressing it.

Comment: What is calc 3 math?